# Express, Passportjs persistent login not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, fetch-api

I'm using Express and Passport to sign in but there is a problem: **the persistent login session doesn't work**.

If I log `req.isAuthenticated()` It's alway `false`.

I'm using **Custom Callback** from [Passport](http://passportjs.org/docs/login)
and `fetch` to make the call. The data received from `fetch` is working: `{ success: true, user }`.

When I'm not using the custom callback (see below) it's working.

**Works**

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                                    failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

**Not working**

**app.js**

```
app.use(morgan('tiny'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.static(assetPath))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true },
  })
)
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
```

**routes.js**

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', ({ user, err, message }) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.send({ user, err, message })
    }

    if (!user) {
      return res.send({ user, err, message })
    }

    req.login(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err)
      }
      return res.send({ success: true, user })
    })
  })(req, res, next)
})
```

**Client:**

```
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'include',
      body: JSON.stringify(values),
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the persistent login is stored in session, which uses a signed cookie to identify future requests as part of the same session.

Also by default, [fetch doesn't send cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

You can send cookies by including them:

```
fetch(url, {  
  credentials: 'include'  
});
```

Or you can use a more modern mechanism for authentication like JWTs.  Up to you.

**UPDATE**

Also, you are setting `secure:true` on your session, which is the default and also means the requests must happen over https, or else the cookies will be stripped out.  If you're not using https, then set `secure:false`.  For best results, make that a configuration setting you can change for production or development, since you always want to use https in production.

Comment: Thank you Paul, I added your code but still have the issue. :/

Comment: Updated with something else I noted about your current code.

Comment: Paul thank you so much for your time. it seems to work now but why it was working without the custom callback?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Did you stop using your custom callback? Or do you mean when you changed the cookie parameters as I suggested?